# How can i auto start Wamp Xampp and tomcat after reboot server

Tags: batch-file, tomcat, xampp, wampserver

I use windows server 2008

after i restart server i want to auto start `wamp` `xampp` and `tomcat` automatic

how can i write batch to start all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a **shortcut to Wamp/Xampp Control Panel** in `Start Menu > Programs > Startup` folder. Also, you should configure in Wamp to automatically start servers when Wamp starts.

There are other ways to do this, but this is simplest. You do not need to create a batch file for this.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

where to configure Wamp to automatically start Can Xampp do like Wamp?

and how about tomcat?

Comment: In XAMPP, you can do this by clicking on Services option in XAMPP Control Panel. Tomcat also comes with Xampp, so that should solve your problem. In WAMP, if you leave any service in online mode, it will automatically start next time when WAMP starts.

Comment: My tomcat is not auto start after Xampp in the case i use manual start tomcat every time where can i set to auto start after xampp?

Comment: Update information my friend tell me i don't use TOMCAT from Xampp Can i auto start from reboot?

Comment: Sorry, I was away. I was little wrong in prev comment. In XAMPP you go to Config option and check the services to start when XAMPP starts. After this, when you have placed shortcut to XAMPP control panel in Startup folder, it will start automatically.